# GitLab community edition - docker support

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I would like to know if the community edition of GitLab (Self hosted) has support for a CI process that would include:

1. Creation of docker containers (docker-compose or Dockerfile)
2. Save custom docker images to a docker Registry in GitLab
3. Integrate ansible To manage configuration items

I checked the pricing / feature compare section of their website but I wasn’t able to find this info.  Wondering if any fellow stack overflowers that are using this framework already can help out.

Thanks

Comment: Just following up. Did you answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a free GitLab CE account and try it out. Here's what I found:

### Docker Images and Registry

GitLab CE comes with a Package Registry (`Maven`, `NuGet`, `PyPi`, etc.) and Container Registry (for `Docker` images). However, I don't think GitLab will provide free storage for your packages. The benefit is full integration in your CI/CD pipeline. You'll need to host your own server, as described in [How to Build Docker Images and Host a Docker Image Repository with GitLab](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-docker-images-and-host-a-docker-image-repository-with-gitlab). The official docs are at [GitLab Container Registry](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/).

Once you've setup your `Docker` images/registry, you can configure GitLab CE to run various jobs in Docker containers. It's as easy as specifying the name of the image in an `image` field in `gitlab-ci.yml`. The images will run on an application called a `Runner` on a VM or bare metal. You can setup your own `Runners` in `AWS`/`GCP`/`Azure` or even on your own laptop, but GitLab CE also provides 2000 free pipeline-minutes per month hosted on `GCP`. Instructions for setting up GitLab Runners can be found at https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/.

### Ansible Integration

Once you get your docker images/registry and runners set up, you can store the Ansible binaries and dependencies in the docker images. You can execute the playbooks from the `script` section of a job defined in `gitlab-ci.yml`. [Using Ansible and GitLab a Infrastructure-for-Code](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/01/using-ansible-and-gitlab-as-infrastructure-for-code/). You can read some great tutorials [here](https://blog.callr.tech/gitlab-ansible-docker-ci-cd/) and [here](https://www.bevuta.com/en/blog/continuous-delivery-with-gitlab-ci-and-ansible-part-1/).